# jquery on click event input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Imagine this: i have multiple divs with attr "data-question-id" and inside this divs i have one or more inputs that may or may not have a attr "has-next-question". See the example below:

```
<div data-question-id="5">
<input type="radio" has-next-question="true" value="2"> test1
<input type="radio" value="3"> test2
</div>

<div data-question-id="6">
<input type="radio" has-next-question="true" value="5"> test3
<input type="radio" has-next-question="true" value="7"> test4
</div>
```

As you can see in the first div i have two inputs, but one doesnt have the attr "has-next-question". 
My question is, how can i bind a click event on the input that have a parent div with attr "data-question-id" and this div have at least an input with attr "has-next-question".

I already accomplish this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'div[data-question-id] input', function(e) {
          alert('click');
});
```

any help?
thanks guys

Edit:
Changed attr "has-next-question" because its a invalid html attribute.

Imagine this: if i click in "test1" it should trigger the event, but if i click in "test2" it should too, because the parent div with attr "data-question-id" have at least one input with attr "has-next-question", corresponding to the "test1". If there is none input with attr "has-next-question" in the parent div, the event shouldnt trigger.

Comment: `$(document).on('click', 'div[data-question-id] input[has-next-question="true"]', function(e) {` ?

Comment: I know it is not exactly what you are asking, but since the "has-next=question='true'" is not an html attribute, why don't you make this a class name then trigger on that? It looks like you only use it when there is a next question anyways, there are no 'false' values. $(document).on('click', 'div[data-question-id] input .has-next-question, function(e) {
          alert('click');
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not correct html. `has-next-question` is not a valid attribute.

But this should work,

```
$(document).on('click', 'div[data-question-id] input[has-next-question]', function(e) {
          alert('click');
});
```

***Edit: (after change in original question),***

No, you cannot make a selector out of that. jQuery uses CSS selector and they do not work from child to parent.

However, you can do something like this,

```
$(document).on('click', 'div[data-question-id] input', function(e) {
       if($(this).parent().find('[has-next-question]').length === 0 ) return;

       // Other code which needs to be executed.
});
```

i.e. if parent does not have child with `[has-next-question]` attribute, then comes out from the function.

Comment: thanks for the tip about my invalid attribute. see my answer at Ricardo Lohmann comment.

Comment: that solution resolve my problem, thanks. I will accept your answer

Answer (score 3):

You did it for the `div`, so repeat it.

```
div[data-question-id] input[has-next-question]
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fxs3c/)

Comment: maybe and didnt make myself clear, imagine this: if i click in "test1" it should trigger the event, but if i trigger in "test2" it should too, because the parent div with attr "data-question-id" have at least one input with attr "has-next-question", corresponding to the "test1". The trigger of the event must on trigger only when there is none input with attr "has-next-question"

Answer (score 1):

Just extend your selector:

```
$(document).on('click', "div[data-question-id] input[has-next-question='true']", function(e) {
          alert('click');
});
```